# Create multiple Window Plugin with Python for QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

What is the smoothest way to design a multiple Windows Python Plugin for QGIS. Should I create multiple Qt-Designer Windows and try to conect them, or is there a way to create the Windows in one Qt-Design .ui-File and have the ability to change the window which is open via a Button. I'm new into PyGIS Plugin Programming.

Comment: If your windows are the same, one `.ui` file with only one widget is enough. After, you can instanciate that widget as many as you want (and as many as your computer can).

Comment: The Windows are different in design and functions. I want to use every Window for one Step in the Workflow.

Comment: you can create multiple windows with only one UI file, you can create a stack widget (as layer properties dialog in QGIS, clicking on tabs on the left change the content on the right, but it's one widget).

Comment: I'd recomment to avoid Qt-Designer at all. Sometimes you may need more than this editor can provide. Most of actions and design features can be set in `pyqt5`. There you can also create multiple windows in separate classes that also joined with each other.